# What does the Matlab error Unsupported number of channels mean

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, wav

I am VERY new to Matlab and am trying to generate a .wav file, but I keep getting an Unsupported number of Channels error.  Here is my code.

```
TTL = zeros(2, 2205);
TTL(1,1:2205) = 2;
audiowrite('hereitis.wav', TTL, 44100, 'BitsPerSample', 16);
```

I'm fairly certain that my problem is with TTL since I have used Matlab once or twice in the past to generate a .wav file.  What I am trying to do is save a sound that another person is transmitting over analog using the Matlab Data Acquisition Toolbox.  I don't think that I am too far off the mark since I have been able to play the sound using Sound(TTL, 44100);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems here.

First, as `help audiowrite` says:

> Stereo data should be specified as a matrix with two columns.

But you have two rows, so you need to change it. If you run changed code, you'll get warning:

```
Warning: Data clipped when writing file. 
>In audiowrite>clipInputData at 390   
In audiowrite at 166
```

It means you need to use proper data type for your signal (in this case int16). So after this modifications we come to this code:

```
TTL = int16(zeros(2205, 2));
TTL(1:2205, 1) = 2;
audiowrite('hereitis.wav', TTL, 44100, 'BitsPerSample', 16);
```